# differential osquery query output to "catchall" topic

Tags: apache-kafka, osquery

I'm using [osquery](https://osquery.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction/using-osqueryd/) to monitor servers on my network. The following `osquery.conf` captures snapshots, every minute, of the processes communicating over the network ports and publishes that data to Kafka:

```
{
  "options": {
    "logger_kafka_brokers": "cp01.woolford.io:9092,cp02.woolford.io:9092,cp03.woolford.io:9092",
    "logger_kafka_topic": "base_topic",
    "logger_kafka_acks": "1"
  },
  "packs": {
    "system-snapshot": {
      "queries": {
        "processes_by_port": {
          "query": "select u.username, p.pid, p.name, pos.local_address, pos.local_port, pos.remote_address, pos.remote_port from processes p join users u on u.uid = p.uid join process_open_sockets pos on pos.pid=p.pid where pos.remote_port != '0'",
          "interval": 60,
          "snapshot": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "kafka_topics": {
    "process-port": [
      "pack_system-snapshot_processes_by_port"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here's an example of the output from the query:

```
osquery> select u.username, p.pid, p.name, pos.local_address, pos.local_port, pos.remote_address, pos.remote_port from processes p join users u on u.uid = p.uid join process_open_sockets pos on pos.pid=p.pid where pos.remote_port != '0';
+--------------------+-------+---------------+------------------+------------+------------------+-------------+
| username           | pid   | name          | local_address    | local_port | remote_address   | remote_port |
+--------------------+-------+---------------+------------------+------------+------------------+-------------+
| cp-kafka-connect   | 13646 | java          | 10.0.1.41        | 49018      | 10.0.1.41        | 9092        |
| cp-kafka-connect   | 13646 | java          | 10.0.1.41        | 49028      | 10.0.1.41        | 9092        |
| cp-kafka-connect   | 13646 | java          | 10.0.1.41        | 49026      | 10.0.1.41        | 9092        |
| cp-kafka-connect   | 13646 | java          | 10.0.1.41        | 50558      | 10.0.1.43        | 9092        |
| cp-kafka-connect   | 13646 | java          | 10.0.1.41        | 50554      | 10.0.1.43        | 9092        |
| cp-kafka-connect   | 13646 | java          | 10.0.1.41        | 49014      | 10.0.1.41        | 9092        |
| root               | 1505  | sssd_be       | 10.0.1.41        | 46436      | 10.0.1.89        | 389         |
...
| cp-ksql            | 1757  | java          | 10.0.1.41        | 56180      | 10.0.1.41        | 9092        |
| cp-ksql            | 1757  | java          | 10.0.1.41        | 53878      | 10.0.1.43        | 9092        |
| root               | 19684 | sshd          | 10.0.1.41        | 22         | 10.0.1.53        | 50238       |
| root               | 24082 | sshd          | 10.0.1.41        | 22         | 10.0.1.53        | 51233       |
| root               | 24107 | java          | 10.0.1.41        | 56052      | 10.0.1.41        | 9092        |
| root               | 24107 | java          | 10.0.1.41        | 56054      | 10.0.1.41        | 9092        |
| cp-schema-registry | 24694 | java          | 10.0.1.41        | 50742      | 10.0.1.31        | 2181        |
| cp-schema-registry | 24694 | java          | 10.0.1.41        | 47150      | 10.0.1.42        | 9093        |
| cp-schema-registry | 24694 | java          | 10.0.1.41        | 58068      | 10.0.1.41        | 9093        |
| cp-schema-registry | 24694 | java          | 10.0.1.41        | 47152      | 10.0.1.42        | 9093        |
| root               | 25782 | osqueryd      | 10.0.1.41        | 57700      | 10.0.1.43        | 9092        |
| root               | 25782 | osqueryd      | 10.0.1.41        | 56188      | 10.0.1.41        | 9092        |
+--------------------+-------+---------------+------------------+------------+------------------+-------------+
```

Instead of snapshots, I'd like osquery to capture differentials, i.e. to only publish the changes to Kafka.

I tried toggling the snapshot property from true to false. My expectation was that osquery would send the changes. For some reason, when I set `"snapshot": false`, no data is published to the `process-port` topic. Instead, all the data is routed to the catchall `base_topic`.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

### Update:

I think I'm running into this bug: https://github.com/osquery/osquery/issues/5559

Here's a video walk-through: https://youtu.be/sPdlBBKgJmY

I filed a bug report, with steps to reproduce, in case it's not the same issue: https://github.com/osquery/osquery/issues/5890

Answer (score 0):

Given the context, I can't immediately tell what is causing the issue you are experiencing.

In order to debug this, I would first try using the `filesystem` logger plugin instead of (or in addition to) the Kafka logger.

Do you get results to the Kafka topic when the query is configured as a snapshot? If so, are you able to verify that the results are actually changing such that a diff should be generate when the query runs in differential mode?

Can you see results logged locally when you use `--logger_plugin=filesystem,kafka`?

Comment: When the snapshot is true, the messages are routed to the expected topic (i.e. `process-port`). When the snapshot is false, all the messages are routed to the "catchall" `base_topic`. That seems like a bug to me.

Comment: That does sound like a bug. Please file an issue in the github.com/osquery/osquery repository.

Comment: Thanks, @Zach. This was fixed in the latest release.